# How we can have access to an array into a mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm totally new in MapReduce programming and in my first MR code, I have this question. In my mapper, I need to have access to a 2D array that has been created and filled before the mapper in the main class. How can I have access to it? Should I export it into txt and try to read it in the mapper? If so, how should in insert it into mapper? I have no idea how should I make it available? My code is in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this couple of ways.

1. After you created the 2D array, you can load this file into HDFS and then use DistributedCache in Java M/R API to access this data in your mapper/reducer code.  Take a look at this: http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html
2. If your data is not too large and you have an object that represents this data which is serializable and quite small you can pass it along via the job Configuration.  Serialize it and include a base64 encoded version of it in the Configuration. Then you can access this data in mapper/reducer: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#set(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)